# AngularJS, Typescript passing variables through a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working on an application using AngularJS, now the thing is, I need to pass an URL when I click on a menu button so I can use that URL in an iframe on in another view with another controller. I've been trying a lot of things and ran through like whole Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find a solution for my problem..

**My service:**

```
module Services {
    export class PassUrlService {

        getUrl;
        setUrl;
        givenUrl;

        constructor($scope) {
            this.getUrl = function() {
                return this.givenUrl;
            }

            this.setUrl = function (value: string) {
                this.givenUrl = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**My controller:**

```
module Controllers {
    export class MainController {

        data = [];
        sce;
        IframeUrl;

        constructor($scope, $sce) {
            $scope.data = this.data;
            $scope.vm = this;
            this.sce = $sce;
        }

        setIframeUrl = function (url) {
            this.IframeUrl = Services.PassUrlService.setUrl(this.sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url));
            debugger;
        }

    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> error TS2339: Property 'setUrl' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   PassUrlService'.

I hope someone can help me solving this problem, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not injecting your Service in the controller, try with the sample below

```
service: Services.PassUrlService

constructor($scope, $sce, service: Services.PassUrlService ) {
        $scope.data = this.data;
        $scope.vm = this;
        this.sce = $sce;
        this.service = service
    }
```